# Read line > compress it > remove line with bash

Tags: bash, gzip

Few years ago I was using handy bash oneliner. It was doing something like:

```
cat file.log && rm -f file.log | gzip -9 > file.gz
```

But it was rather processed line by line. I was using in when there were no space left on drive, and I want to process it on flow.

I'm trying to recall how to do it, but its pretty hard :)

Comment: Do what? That command certainly isn't what you were doing; it simply outputs the file once, removes it, and pipes the output of `rm` (which is empty) to `gzip`.

Comment: I know, that I screwed logic. Still looking for correct implementation.
I thought about reading file in loop, but I guess it might be easier. 

fe.:
`
    fielpath="/tmp/foo"
    declare -i lineno=0
    while read -r line; do
            echo "$line" | gzip -9 > "$filepath".gz 
            let ++lineno
            sed -i "1 d" "$fielpath"
    done < "$fielpath"
`

But AFAIR It is possible to do it as handy oneliner.

Answer (score 0):

The answear is:

```
fielpath="/tmp/foo"
declare -i lineno=0
while read -r line; do
        echo "$line" | gzip -9 >> "$filepath".gz 
        let ++lineno
        sed -i "1 d" "$fielpath"
done < "$fielpath"
```

but still considering how to do it as a handy oneliner